# "Banking" alternatives for digit characters?

Tags: characters, number

I heard, that there are more complex "banking" alternatives for digit characters:

> 一二三四五六七八九十

provided in order to fraud protect.

Is this true and how can I find a table for them?

May be 零 is and example replacement for 〇 but I am not sure.

Answer (score 4):

0、1、2、3、4、5、6、7、8、9、10、100、1,000(1K)、10,000(10K)、100,000,000(100M)

Traditional Chinese
零、壹、 貳、參、肆、伍、陸、柒、捌、玖、拾、佰、仟、萬、億

or

Simplified Chinese
零、壹、 贰、叁、肆、伍、陆、柒、捌、玖、拾、佰、仟、万、亿